# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Am getting **"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')** error  Redux in my react redux application. I made a very simple react redux application. but am keep getting this error. searched about this error on Internet unfortunately didn't get any solution.

**Redux folder structure:**

```
src >> state(folder) >> store.js
reducer.js
```

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState={
    user:[]
}


export const userReducer=(state=initialState,action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "TEST_DATA":
                return state
        default:
            return state
    }
 
}
```

**store.js**

```
import {createStore,applyMiddleware} from "redux"
import {userReducer} from './reducer'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'


export const store=createStore(userReducer,composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './state/store'


ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
  <App />
</Provider>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Tried to access state in App.jsx component**

```
console.log(useSelector(state=>state))
```

am trying to fix it from last 3-4 days. Please help me am new to react and redux.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Following steps fixed the issue for me

1. Check your react version in package.json
2. If the react version is 18, then update "react-redux" package using npm i react-redux
3. the "react-redux" package should have version 8 in package.json
4. run npm start

Snippet from package.json file:

```
"react": "^18.1.0",
"react-dom": "^18.1.0",
"react-redux": "^8.0.1",
```

Comment: I am using react-redux 8.0.5 still facing this error.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone runs into this error with Next.js v13+ using the App directory (AKA App Router) then it could be because you're trying to use useMemo in a server component.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do one thing install all these one more time and you will get free from this error.
i.e  npm i redux react-redux redux-thunk

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34471850)

Answer (score 1):

while you running script `npm i redux` , check your `package.json` is same in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

For ones who using Next.js App directory, you need `'use client'` at the begining of the file and make sure that

```
// Wrong 
export async default function Page({ params }) {

// Correct
export default function Page({ params }) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because redux toolkit is used now and redux is deprecated. Delete node modules and reinstall using this command npm install --legacy-peer-deps.

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are not in the correct folder make sure you install react-redux in the correct react folder
eg:cd my-app
npm i react-redux

Answer (score -1):

Mine was a simple mistake from the import. React was capitalized.

```
// import { useMemo } from "React";
import { useMemo } from "react";
```